# Action at set time does not work

Tags: c#, time

I dont know, why it does not write anything at the set time

```
       DateTime trolltime = new DateTime(2013, 6, 24, 9, 25, 21); //nevermind the time
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        goto1:
        if (trolltime == now)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("blahblah");
        }

        else
        {
            goto goto1;
        }
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: goto comes from VB is a directive to go to specific label..

Comment: @ojlovecd - I think it's obvious that he wants to print out `blahblah` if `trolltime` is equal to the current date/time.

Answer (score 2):

When you are comparing two `DateTime` objects, internal [Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) are compared. Not only seconds. So, there is very small chance that `DateTime.Now` will have same `Ticks` as your `DateTime(2013, 6, 24, 9, 25, 21)` instance.

If you want to start something approximately at 9:25:21, you can create [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and set it's delay to time span between your time and current time:

```
DateTime trolltime = new DateTime(2013, 6, 24, 9, 25, 21);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Timer timer = new Timer(callback, state, trolltime - now, TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Comment: my Visual Studio doesn´t know the Timer method!

Comment: @MancatoIlDottore it is not a method. Timer is a class from System.Threading namespace. See a link to msdn

Answer (score 1):

After initialization, `trolltime` and `now` are probably different. Neither is changed, so they stay different.

Comment: Henrik is 100% true. By the way, c# makes use of Timers to deal with this kind of situation. Here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Because probably `trolltime` and `now` are not equal at all and your program skip `if` part and goes to `else` part.

But in your `else` part, you are going to `goto1` line with [`goto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And that's cause infinite loop in your program.